# Factoring $\sum_{sym}a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> **Problem:** Factor $$\sum_{sym}a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2$$

---

I'm not too sure how to factor this, nor do I understand what the "sym" means at the bottom of the sigma notation. I'm guessing that this means some sort of symmetry, or cycle through, but I'm not exactly $100\%$ sure.

Any help would be okay. Including hints!

Comment: @IanMiller Is the complete factorization $$(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2$$

Comment: That looks correct. Post your working as an answer to your own question to help others who visit.

Comment: I just noticed that my earlier comment didn't include all combinations. It should have been six sets of brackets not three so I'll remove the comment and repost a new corrected one.

Comment: @IanMiller Sure. I've posted the answer now.

Comment: Yes $sym$ means all variations of $a$,$b$ and $c$ so the expression is actually: $$(a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2) + (b^4c^2-b^4ca-b^3c^3+2b^3c^2a-b^2c^2a^2) + (c^4a^2-c^4ab-c^3a^3+2c^3a^2b-c^2a^2b^2) + (b^4a^2-b^4ac-b^3a^3+2b^3a^2c-b^2a^2c^2) + (a^4c^2-a^4cb-a^3c^3+2a^3c^2b-a^2c^2b^2) + (c^4b^2-c^4ba-c^3b^3+2c^3b^2a-c^2b^2a^2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding out, we (unfortunately) get $$a^4b^2-2a^4bc+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c+2a^3bc^2-2a^3c^3+a^2b^4+2a^2b^3c-6a^2b^2c^2+2a^2bc^3+a^2c^4-2ab^4c+2ab^3c^2+2ab^2c^3-2abc^4+b^4c^2-2b^3c^3+b^2c^4\tag1$$
And factoring out $a^4$ from the first three constants, $a^3$ from the next $4$ constants, and so on, we obtain $$a^4(b^2-2bc+c^2)+a^3(-2b^3+2b^2c+2bc^2-2c^3)+a^2(b^4+2b^3c-6b^2c^2+2bc^3+c^4)+a(-2b^4c+2b^3c^2+2b^2c^3-2bc^4)+(b^4c^2-2b^3c^3+b^2c^4)\tag2$$
And factoring the expressions inside the parenthesis, we get the factorization as $$(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2$$ as our answer.